# Fetch API Get request not recognizing values from input form

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am trying to get values from a fetch request using input from a form with player first and last name. The return json has a total size of 0 but when I hard code the value of the names I do get the correct info. I've tried switching the fetch request many different ways but I can't get the response I am looking for.

The API Docs says:

*If you’re using a single search term i.e. using ‘cespedes’ instead of ‘yoenis cespedes’, you’ll need to append a ‘%25’ character to your search term. Without it, the request will return 500.*

```
<body>

    <div>
      <form action="">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" /><br />
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>

<script>

      fetch(
        'http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam?sport_code=%27mlb%27&active_sw=%27Y%27&name_part=%27' +
          'fname' +
          '_' +
          'lname' +
          '%27'
      )

        .then(function test(res) {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(function test1(data) {
          console.log('data', data);
});
    </script>
  </body>
```

When i use this fetch with the name included, it returns the correct json.

```
http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam?sport_code=%27mlb%27&active_sw=%27Y%27&name_part=%27francisco_lindor%25%27
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating your fetch url, you have to actually include the form values.

You current code

```
'http://...&name_part=%27' + 'fname' + '_' + 'lname' + '%27'
```

will always result in

```
"http://...&name_part='fname_lname'"
```

regardless of the form inputs because you are just concatenating string literals here. You can check that by logging the urls you create before sending them.

You have to get the form values in javascript to send them.
For example, you could get the values of the inputs and keep them in variables like this:

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
```

Then you can use those values to create your url:

```
var url = 'http://...&name_part=%27' + fname + '_' + lname + '%27';
```

Keep an eye on the `fname` and `lname`. There are no quotes around them so javascript will use the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your current fetch sends `fname` and `lname` as strings instead of using their actual values. This should work just fine:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const fname = document.getElementById('fname');
const lname = document.getElementById('lname');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(`http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam?sport_code=%27mlb%27&active_sw=%27Y%27&name_part=%27${fname.value}_${lname.value}%27`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
})
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Aaron" /><br />
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Judge" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```